# Strips cut on video mode

Tags: video-sequence-editor, shortcut, knife-tool

I don't know if you already tried to edit a serie of videos on blender. It's very hard because of the mosto common tool isnt there.

WHAT WE DO:
I'm pointing player cursor on a place in strip, cutting with Knife (k) moving to the other point, cutting with knife, selecting the part in between, deleting (del) and removing gaps (backspace)

WHAT I WANT TO DO:
Select the range, press a button and see that the selection was deleted and the strip at right moved left filling the gap.

SO QUESTIONS:
Please, there is a mode to do this? Without or with free add-ons.
Can I suggest that this second mode, if it exists, should be standard?

Comment: Alas, the VSE has received little attention from developers until recently. It's not (yet) meant for serious video editing..  A search for "blender vse addons" turns up several that look like they might do what you want; but I don't use any of them so I can recommend for or against.

Comment: Thanks, I will search them. I tried other terms, but unsuccessfully. Maybe "vse" would be the difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender comes with an add-on called Power Sequencer, you'll need to look through the add-ons and enable it(Preferences/Add-ons/Sequencer).
It's got a tool called Mouse Trim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiLmDhmMVAM
I believe, this is what you want?

You'll find the Power Sequencer manual on all of the tools included here: https://www.gdquest.com/docs/power-sequencer/reference/

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it helps a lot. Probably there is no free method to select the strips like in audacity, but the ctrl+click moves do that.
Thanks, I gave up this topic and now you found a good solution.

Comment: @DanielCapua Some work was done on a Blade Tool patch, but it was never committed: https://developer.blender.org/D7379